# Python pandas dataframe set_name length issue expecting one argument but is given two

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, dataframe

So I have this prep_dat function and I am giving it the following csv data:

```
identifier,Hugo_Symbol,Tumor_Sample_Barcode,Variant_Classification,patient
1,patient,a,Silent,6
22,mutated,d,e,7
1,Hugo_Symbol,f,g,88
```

within this prep_data function, there is this line

```
  gene_mutation_df.index.set_names(['Hugo_Symbol', 'patient'], inplace=True)
```

However, it keeps erring out when it gets to the line saying

```
ValueError: Length of new names must be 1, got 2
```

Is there something wrong with the line or is it something wrong with the function

Here is the whole source code

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
PRIMARY_TUMOR_PATIENT_ID_REGEX = '^.{4}-.{2}-.{4}-01.*'
SHORTEN_PATIENT_REGEX = '^(.{4}-.{2}-.{4}).*'

def mutations_for_gene(df):
  mutated_patients = df['identifier'].unique()
  return pd.DataFrame({'mutated': np.ones(len(mutated_patients))}, index=mutated_patients)
  
def prep_data(mutation_path):
  df = pd.read_csv(mutation_path, low_memory=True, dtype=str, header = 0)#Line 24 reads in a line memory csv file from the given path and parses it based on '\t' delimators, and casts the data to str
  
  df = df[~df['Hugo_Symbol'].str.contains('Hugo_Symbol')] #analyzes the 'Hugo_Symbol' heading within the data and makes a new dataframe where any row that contains 'Hugo_Symbol' is dropped

  df['Hugo_Symbol'] = '\'' + df['Hugo_Symbol'].astype(str) # Appends ''\'' to all the data remaining in that column
  
  df['Tumor_Sample_Barcode'] = df['Tumor_Sample_Barcode'].str.strip() #strips away whitespace from the data within this heading
  non_silent = df.where(df['Variant_Classification'] != 'Silent') #creates a new dataframe where the data within the column 'Variant_Classification' is not equal to 'Silent'

  df = non_silent.dropna(subset=['Variant_Classification']) #Drops all the rows that are missing at least one element
  
  non_01_barcodes = df[~df['Tumor_Sample_Barcode'].str.contains(PRIMARY_TUMOR_PATIENT_ID_REGEX)]['Tumor_Sample_Barcode'] #Creates a new dataframe of all the data within the 'Tumor_Sample_Barcode' column that does not match the PRIMARY_TUMOR_PATIENT_ID_REGEX
  #TODO: Double check that the extra ['Tumor_Sample_Barcode'] serves no purpose
  df = df.drop(non_01_barcodes.index)
  print(df)
  shortened_patients = df['Tumor_Sample_Barcode'].str.extract(SHORTEN_PATIENT_REGEX, expand=False)
  df['identifier'] = shortened_patients
  
  gene_mutation_df = df.groupby(['Hugo_Symbol']).apply(mutations_for_gene)
  gene_mutation_df.index.set_names(['Hugo_Symbol', 'patient'], inplace=True)
  gene_mutation_df = gene_mutation_df.reset_index()
  gene_patient_mutations = gene_mutation_df.pivot(index='Hugo_Symbol', columns='patient', values='mutated')
  
  return gene_patient_mutations.transpose().fillna(0)
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated( I know this wasn't to specific, Im still trying to work out what this function does exactly and how I could make data to test it)

Comment: `gene_mutation_df.index.set_name` is used for setting names for an already existing index. You have just 1 index (I mean not a multiindex) , you might instead want to use `gene_mutation_df.set_index(['Hugo_Symbol', 'patient'], inplace=True)`

Comment: But I am using that already

Comment: I couldn't see that in your code ,also if you `set_index` columns, you might not have to set index names again unless you want to rename the index

Comment: This is what my code says: gene_mutation_df.index.set_names(['Hugo_Symbol', 'patient'], inplace=True)                                                                                                     Can you give an example of the set_index please ?

Comment: I have already given you the code with `set_index()` which you should replace `gene_mutation_df.index.set_name` with, did you try that ? :)

Comment: So I did that and I ended up with this:  gene_mutation_df.set_index(['Hugo_Symbol', 'patient'], inplace=True), now it gives this error: KeyError: "None of ['Hugo_Symbol', 'patient'] are in the columns", which doesn't make sense because when I print the data those are two of the columns that show up

Comment: May be there are extra spaces, check for them too, maybe you can first try `df.columns = df.columns.str.strip()` and then try what you were trying

Comment: This doesn't seem to help: gene_mutation_df.columns = gene_mutation_df.columns.str.strip(), and there don't seem to be residual spaces either